# How to use the models under tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/models?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm looking into training an object detection network using Tensorflow, and I had a look at the TF2 Model Zoo. I noticed that there are noticeably less models there than in the directory `/models/research/models/`, including the MobileDet with SSDLite developed for the jetson xavier.

To clarify, the readme says that there is a MobileDet GPU with SSDLite, and that the model and checkpoints trained on COCO are provided, yet I couldn't find them anywhere in the repo.

How is one supposed to use those models?

I already have a custom-trained MobileDetv3 for image classification, and I was hoping to see a way to turn the network into an object detection network, in accordance with the MobileDetv3 paper. If this is not straightforward, training one network from scratch could be ok too, I just need to know where to even start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use the object detection API, you can't use your existing model. You have to choose from a list of models [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) for v2 and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md) for v1

The documentation is very well maintained and the steps to train or validate or run inference (test) on custom data is very well explained [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) by the TensorFlow team. The link is meant for TensorFlow version v2. However, if you wish to use v1, the process is fairly similar and there are numerous blogs/videos explaining how to go about it

Comment: thanks, i looked through the github but did not find the documentation you linked (3rd link)
it's a bit disappointing seeing there is no mobilenetv3 or ssdlite implementatio for tf2, or seeing the nvidia-developed mobiledet ssd is only for tf1

Comment: Don't look through GitHub, just follow the third link independently. The other 2 GitHub links were just to show the list of available models to use (their usage will be mentioned in the third link) as well